# Hide headers on client side request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest

We will be using react to consume endpoints that request a header to be attached for authorization. The endpoint will be called client-side.
This header key should be secret. However, if the user opens up a terminal she will be able to inspect the request and see the header. Is there a way to hide this header?

One way could be to encrypt this and decrypt on the other side. Is there another way to hide the header via javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to hide this header?

No. It is not possible to give something to the browser without giving it to the user. The user has complete control over the browser.

If you do not trust the user to access the endpoint, then you can't trust their browser to either.

> One way could be to encrypt this and decrypt on the other side.

Not really. That just changes the string that the user has to send to the endpoint in order to access it. You are still giving them that string.

Comment: Hi my friends, whats is the best parctices about this? I have a Forntend with AngularJS and i need to make calls with my client secret but only for my frontend app...